# Shopify-cli - Can't Complete 'shopify app serve' command

Tags: shopify-app

After following the typical steps of the shopify-cli app creation process, while trying to connect the app to the store through the 'shopify app serve' command, it fails. Rather than displaying an error message, it just gets caught at [nodemon] Starting 'Node Serve/Index.Js'.

A few relevant software versions:

Shopify-cli: 2.20.1

Node.js: v16.16.0

Ruby: 3.1.2

[Stopping point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Au3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of the Shopify CLI, which currently is 2.24.0 and if the issue persists please post an issue in the Github repo https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues